# Great circles on a sphere

Tags: geometry, spheres

- What is the maximal number of disjoint regions obtained on the sphere
  by dividing it with $n$ great circles?

For $n= 1$ we have $2$ regions, for $n=2 $ we have $2^2$, for $n=3$ the number is $2^3$,... what next? - what would be the best approach to this problem? How to use geometrical constraints solving it?

... and ...

- Is it possible to find always   $n$ great circles (in the case when the number of regions is maximal) for  such division
  that **areas** of regions  would be equal ? (I suppose not but how to
  prove it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the count:  We use the fact that the Euler characteristic of the sphere is $2$.  A generic configuration of great circles will have $ 2\times \frac {n(n-1)}2=n(n-1)$ vertices and $n\times 2(n-1)$ edges.  Thus we have $$2=\#F_n -2n^2+2n+n^2-n=\#F_n-n^2+n\implies  \boxed {\#F_n=n^2-n+2}$$

As a sanity check we remark that $\#F_1=2,\#F_2=4,\#F_3=9-3+2=8$ as desired.

Comment: So in this case a good approach is linked with graph theory, without even defining equations for circles?

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to use the defining equations for circles in this case....so, yes.  I'm just using basic notions about triangulations.

Comment: Fine, so it's simply a topology, however the second question is probably impossible to solve without geometry... but who knows.. "equal areas" is also a very general condition..

Comment: I didn't think about the area question.  Like you, my gut reaction is that it isn't possible...but i really don't know.